# My IF program is incorrect

Tags: c, if-statement

The problem I am having is the output is always '-1' regardless of what I enter.

The rules I must follow are:
outputs -1 if the input number was less than zero;
outputs 0 if the input number was exactly zero;
outputs 1 if the input number was greater than zero.

Code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
   int number;

printf("please enter a number: ");
scanf("%i", &number);

if("number > 0")
{
printf ("-1");
}
else if ("number == 0")
{
printf("0");
}
else if ("number < 0")
{
printf("1");
}
}
```

Comment: `if("number > 0")` -> `if(number > 0)`!

Comment: Why are you putting things in quotes?

Comment: This is extremely basic syntax.

Comment: Why are you using C functions?

Comment: I am a uni student learning to code.

Comment: George means - why are you not using c++ things like cin and cout given that you have marked the question 'C++'

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still new to C and I get mixed up between C and C++.

Comment: ***if("number > 0")*** if(0) is evaluated as ***if (false)***

Comment: Please indent your code.

Comment: Sometimes I fear that too few C++ teachers actually know any C++ for the human race to survive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these if-else statements

```
if("number > 0")
{
printf ("-1");
}
else if ("number == 0")
{
printf("0");
}
else if ("number < 0")
{
printf("1");
}
```

there are used string literals like for example `"number > 0"` as condition expressions. String literals used in expressions are converted to pointers to their first character and always are unequal to 0. tThus the first condition in the if-else statements yields `true`.

I think you mean the following

```
if( number > 0 )
{
printf ( "1");
         ^^^^^ 
}
else if (number == 0)
{
printf("0");
}
else 
{
printf("-1");
       ^^^^^
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vlad for your help